# Mongoimport error: server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongorestore

I am trying to import some json files to mongodb collections using following command on a server other than mongodb server:

```
mongoimport --host IP --port 27017 -u myuser -p mypass --authenticationDatabase admin --db dbname --collection collection --drop --type json --file absolutejsonfilepath --jsonArray
```

It is throwing following error:

```
server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field.
```

How ever If I hit the same command on mongodb server itself then it works. I have checked all credentials & other details. All details are correct.

**version**

mongodb version: 5.0.8

**update**

if I run the command using -vvvv parameter (for verbose output) then I got this:

```
2022-05-12T12:29:22.261+0000    checking options
2022-05-12T12:29:22.262+0000            dumping with object check disabled
2022-05-12T12:29:22.262+0000    will listen for SIGTERM, SIGINT, and SIGKILL
2022-05-12T12:29:22.283+0000    got error from options parsing: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field.
2022-05-12T12:29:22.283+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: BSON field 'saslContinue.mechanism' is an unknown field.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending hours, I came to know that it was mongoimport version issue on host server. The mongoimport was installed without version number & hence went into errors.

I used following commands to install mongodb tools version 100.5.1

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb-org
sudo apt purge mongodb*
sudo dpkg -i --force-all mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2004-x86_64-100.5.1.deb
```

Comment: for me `--force-overwrite` flag had to be used in the last command and I used mongodb tools version 100.7.0 because it is compatible with mongodb version `5.0`.